# IB Outlet issues - Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, text-recognition

I am making a phone number recognition app based off of [Apple's example code.](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/reading_phone_numbers_in_real_time) I am fairly new to swift and coding in general. When I run the project I get the "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=257, address=0x7e700019ec0ad79)" error on line 68 "previewView.session = captureSession" . I think it has something to do with line 26 "@IBOutlet weak var previewView: PreviewView!" ?

I have a view controller with 2 views and one label. The IB Outlets seem fine for two of them but does not look the same for line 26.. the color of the text PreviewView! is gray instead of blue like the others. Could this be the problem?

```
import AVFoundation

import Vision



class myClass: UIViewController {

    // MARK: - UI objects

    

    @IBOutlet weak var previewView: PreviewView!

    @IBOutlet weak var cutoutView: UIView!

    @IBOutlet weak var numberView: UILabel!

    var maskLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    // Device orientation. Updated whenever the orientation changes to a

    // different supported orientation.

    var currentOrientation = UIDeviceOrientation.portrait

    

    // MARK: - Capture related objects

    private let captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    let captureSessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.apple-samplecode.CaptureSessionQueue")

    

    var captureDevice: AVCaptureDevice?

    

    var videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()

    let videoDataOutputQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.apple-samplecode.VideoDataOutputQueue")

    

    // MARK: - Region of interest (ROI) and text orientation

    // Region of video data output buffer that recognition should be run on.

    // Gets recalculated once the bounds of the preview layer are known.

    var regionOfInterest = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)

    // Orientation of text to search for in the region of interest.

    var textOrientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation.up

    

    // MARK: - Coordinate transforms

    var bufferAspectRatio: Double!

    // Transform from UI orientation to buffer orientation.

    var uiRotationTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity

    // Transform bottom-left coordinates to top-left.

    var bottomToTopTransform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: 0, y: -1)

    // Transform coordinates in ROI to global coordinates (still normalized).

    var roiToGlobalTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity

    

    // Vision -> AVF coordinate transform.

    var visionToAVFTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity

    

    // MARK: - View controller methods

    

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        

        // Set up preview view.

        previewView.session = captureSession

        

        // Set up cutout view.

        cutoutView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

        maskLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

        maskLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd

        cutoutView.layer.mask = maskLayer

        

        // Starting the capture session is a blocking call. Perform setup using

        // a dedicated serial dispatch queue to prevent blocking the main thread.

        captureSessionQueue.async {

            self.setupCamera()

            

            // Calculate region of interest now that the camera is setup.

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                // Figure out initial ROI.

                self.calculateRegionOfInterest()

            }

        }

    }

    

    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {

        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)



        // Only change the current orientation if the new one is landscape or

        // portrait. You can't really do anything about flat or unknown.

        let deviceOrientation = UIDevice.current.orientation

        if deviceOrientation.isPortrait || deviceOrientation.isLandscape {

            currentOrientation = deviceOrientation

        }

        

        // Handle device orientation in the preview layer.

        if let videoPreviewLayerConnection = previewView.videoPreviewLayer.connection {

            if let newVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(deviceOrientation: deviceOrientation) {

                videoPreviewLayerConnection.videoOrientation = newVideoOrientation

            }

        }

        

        // Orientation changed: figure out new region of interest (ROI).

        calculateRegionOfInterest()

    }

    

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

        updateCutout()

    }

    

    // MARK: - Setup

    

    func calculateRegionOfInterest() {

        // In landscape orientation the desired ROI is specified as the ratio of

        // buffer width to height. When the UI is rotated to portrait, keep the

        // vertical size the same (in buffer pixels). Also try to keep the

        // horizontal size the same up to a maximum ratio.

        let desiredHeightRatio = 0.15

        let desiredWidthRatio = 0.6

        let maxPortraitWidth = 0.8

        

        // Figure out size of ROI.

        let size: CGSize

        if currentOrientation.isPortrait || currentOrientation == .unknown {

            size = CGSize(width: min(desiredWidthRatio * bufferAspectRatio, maxPortraitWidth), height: desiredHeightRatio / bufferAspectRatio)

        } else {

            size = CGSize(width: desiredWidthRatio, height: desiredHeightRatio)

        }

        // Make it centered.

        regionOfInterest.origin = CGPoint(x: (1 - size.width) / 2, y: (1 - size.height) / 2)

        regionOfInterest.size = size

        

        // ROI changed, update transform.

        setupOrientationAndTransform()

        

        // Update the cutout to match the new ROI.

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            // Wait for the next run cycle before updating the cutout. This

            // ensures that the preview layer already has its new orientation.

            self.updateCutout()

        }

    }

    

    func updateCutout() {

        // Figure out where the cutout ends up in layer coordinates.

        let roiRectTransform = bottomToTopTransform.concatenating(uiRotationTransform)

        let cutout = previewView.videoPreviewLayer.layerRectConverted(fromMetadataOutputRect: regionOfInterest.applying(roiRectTransform))

        

        // Create the mask.

        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: cutoutView.frame)

        path.append(UIBezierPath(rect: cutout))

        maskLayer.path = path.cgPath

        

        // Move the number view down to under cutout.

        var numFrame = cutout

        numFrame.origin.y += numFrame.size.height

        numberView.frame = numFrame

    }

    

    func setupOrientationAndTransform() {

        // Recalculate the affine transform between Vision coordinates and AVF coordinates.

        

        // Compensate for region of interest.

        let roi = regionOfInterest

        roiToGlobalTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: roi.origin.x, y: roi.origin.y).scaledBy(x: roi.width, y: roi.height)

        

        // Compensate for orientation (buffers always come in the same orientation).

        switch currentOrientation {

        case .landscapeLeft:

            textOrientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation.up

            uiRotationTransform = CGAffineTransform.identity

        case .landscapeRight:

            textOrientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation.down

            uiRotationTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 1, y: 1).rotated(by: CGFloat.pi)

        case .portraitUpsideDown:

            textOrientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation.left

            uiRotationTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 1, y: 0).rotated(by: CGFloat.pi / 2)

        default: // We default everything else to .portraitUp

            textOrientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation.right

            uiRotationTransform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 1).rotated(by: -CGFloat.pi / 2)

        }

        

        // Full Vision ROI to AVF transform.

        visionToAVFTransform = roiToGlobalTransform.concatenating(bottomToTopTransform).concatenating(uiRotationTransform)

    }

    

    func setupCamera() {

        guard let captureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: AVMediaType.video, position: .back) else {

            print("Could not create capture device.")

            return

        }

        self.captureDevice = captureDevice

        

        // NOTE:

        // Requesting 4k buffers allows recognition of smaller text but will

        // consume more power. Use the smallest buffer size necessary to keep

        // down battery usage.

        if captureDevice.supportsSessionPreset(.hd4K3840x2160) {

            captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd4K3840x2160

            bufferAspectRatio = 3840.0 / 2160.0

        } else {

            captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.hd1920x1080

            bufferAspectRatio = 1920.0 / 1080.0

        }

        

        guard let deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice) else {

            print("Could not create device input.")

            return

        }

        if captureSession.canAddInput(deviceInput) {

            captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)

        }

        

        // Configure video data output.

        videoDataOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

        videoDataOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: videoDataOutputQueue)

        videoDataOutput.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_420YpCbCr8BiPlanarFullRange]

        if captureSession.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) {

            captureSession.addOutput(videoDataOutput)

            // NOTE:

            // There is a trade-off to be made here. Enabling stabilization will

            // give temporally more stable results and should help the recognizer

            // converge. But if it's enabled the VideoDataOutput buffers don't

            // match what's displayed on screen, which makes drawing bounding

            // boxes very hard. Disable it in this app to allow drawing detected

            // bounding boxes on screen.

            videoDataOutput.connection(with: AVMediaType.video)?.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = .off

        } else {

            print("Could not add VDO output")

            return

        }

        

        // Set zoom and autofocus to help focus on very small text.

        do {

            try captureDevice.lockForConfiguration()

            captureDevice.videoZoomFactor = 2

            captureDevice.autoFocusRangeRestriction = .near

            captureDevice.unlockForConfiguration()

        } catch {

            print("Could not set zoom level due to error: \(error)")

            return

        }

        

        captureSession.startRunning()

    }

    

    // MARK: - UI drawing and interaction

    

    func showString(string: String) {

        // Found a definite number.

        // Stop the camera synchronously to ensure that no further buffers are

        // received. Then update the number view asynchronously.

        captureSessionQueue.sync {

            self.captureSession.stopRunning()

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.numberView.text = string

                self.numberView.isHidden = false

            }

        }

    }

    

    @IBAction func handleTap(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        captureSessionQueue.async {

            if !self.captureSession.isRunning {

                self.captureSession.startRunning()

            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {

                self.numberView.isHidden = true

            }

        }

    }

}



// MARK: - AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate



extension TextScanViewController: AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {

    

    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

        // This is implemented in VisionViewController.

    }

}



// MARK: - Utility extensions



extension AVCaptureVideoOrientation {

    init?(deviceOrientation: UIDeviceOrientation) {

        switch deviceOrientation {

        case .portrait: self = .portrait

        case .portraitUpsideDown: self = .portraitUpsideDown

        case .landscapeLeft: self = .landscapeRight

        case .landscapeRight: self = .landscapeLeft

        default: return nil

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: You probably haven't connected the outlet from your storyboard scene to the view controller, so the outlet is nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try to reference an `@IBOutlet` object that has **not** been properly connected, you will get this error:

```
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value
```

Since that is not the error you are getting, it must be something else.

***Almost certainly***, you added a `UIView` and connected it to:

```
@IBOutlet weak var previewView: PreviewView!
```

but forgot to set the Custom Class.

When you select that `UIView` in Storyboard, this:

[image]

should look like this:

[image]

(Ignore the "*Module: qt122022*" -- it will auto-fill with the name of your project. Mine just happens to be named qt122022.)

Comment: Thank you! This worked great. Very clear steps too I appreciate that! :)

Answer (score 0):

Check the connection inspector in your storyboard or xib and  check if `previewView` if it has a single reference, it may be that you have more than one or in any case no reference to your IBOulet

[image]